# Are there any C++ style and/or standard example files available?

Tags: c++, coding-style

While there are lots of questions about coding style, beautifying, and enforcement, I haven't found any example C++ files that are used as a quick reference for style. The file should be one or two pages long and exemplify a given coding standard/style.

For example, the Google C++ Style Guide is a great reference, but I think a one to two page piece of code written in their style pinned to a wall would be more useful in day-to-day use.

Do any of these already exist?

Comment: IMO, the Google C++ Style Guide is a steaming pile of doo.

Comment: @John: I wouldn’t go quite as far but besides the plain questionable guidelines there are a lot that cater to backwards compatibility issues that are partial to Google’s internal software (e.g. the guideline not to use exceptions since some older libraries can’t deal with them) so it’s really a bad guideline in general.

Comment: The amazing thing about that pile is that its still there after so many have eaten so much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you say is wrong with Google's style guide? There's a lot of criticism here, but nothing much to substantiate it.

Comment: @Tom: I can't really go in to detail in a comment, but in short the GSG seems to take this approach: "We prohibit many of the facilities we didn't understand when we wrote the guide, and we prohibit others because we assume programmers are dumb.  And we insist you use our favorite indenting style because we have a hard time reading anything else."  The GSG limits the programmer too much.

Comment: What's right about it?  They should have read chapter one of "C++ Coding Standards"

Comment: @John:  To take a more charitable view of the Google standards, they were written when they had a lot of different compilers, some of them old and lame, and they wanted the code to run on all of them.  They don't assume all programmers are dumb, just enough so they don't dare risk anything complicated and useful.  In other words, there are some halfway decent reasons why it became a steaming pile of doo.

Comment: @David:  I do agree with you.  And I get the need to maintain backward compatibility & not break legacy systems.  But there's no excuse for their coding style to not evolve as the state of the art evolves.  That's what bugs me the most.

Comment: [Just adopt the style already in use in the project/team you're joining](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/naming-conventions-for-variables/33555#33555).

Answer (score 3):

I think Bjarne's [JSF AV C++ Coding Standards (doc)](http://www.jsf.mil/downloads/documents/JSF_AV_C++_Coding_Standards_Rev_C.doc) is pretty awesome. Although it's a long read, and it goes against stuff you can use safely in everyday applications, etc, it's a good document.

This is because it explains the reasons and gives examples of when **it's ok to break the rules** and why, therefore it's a veritable tome of knowledge and experience.

Instant c++ level up! :)

Comment: It's also a bit old (some things are banned due to current lack of tool support), and designed for a more rigorous development procedure than most of us like.  It also includes purely stylistic issues on a similar level to substantive ones.  ("Don't use function-style macros" is a generally good idea, while "Separate words in identifiers with underscores" is good when that's the style in use.)  Recommended reading because of the rationales, but don't take the details too seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would consider it 'style' (I would) but Scott Meyer's [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEGMBO) is a great book for learning good practices in c++. In my opinion if you exercise these practices your 'style' will follow.

Note that it contains lots of examples to re-enforce his lessons. That being said there isn't a large code sample that you can just browse to look at style. Again i think with good practices in place the style will follow.

Comment: +1 Meyer's Effective C++ books should be required reading for every C++ programmer, IMO.